# Block website in linux

Tags: linux, website, blocking

I want to know how to block all the websites on Linux  and not just from the host file  . so the website doesn't show any kind of issue on my website if I click on any kind of suspicious links so I know what is the behind move that length so it doesn't sound any kind of packet to server

With this method I want to block all the IP address and DNS servers online environment. what example if someone want to send your suspicious thing if I open that link so it doesn't make any kind of issue for me I only allow the few of the website which add trusted and not going to steal my personal information from my area.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: define what you means by `Len X`

Comment: https://geekflare.com/url-blacklist-and-fix/

Comment: not helpful what  i want is not there

Comment: Even after your edit, it's still not clear what is asked here

Comment: I think he wants to block all websites except the ones on a whitelist.

Comment: The problem with this idea is modern websites don’t all rely on assets and connections to one single host. So that “site” technically loads as expected by then possibly broken images, CSS and such occur.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are various tools that can tell Linux to behave a certain way when network traffic flows through it - including refusing to allow reception or origination of traffic from/to specific IP addresses.

A common one is `iptables` - and if you are dealing with large numbers of addresses, you'll want to use `ipset` as well, which basically lets you create rules that deal with large numbers of addresses in a group quickly (versus making many number of rules for specific IP addresses).

Unfortunately Linux networking is complicated because it's very flexible (it can and is used in various profressional networking products, including most likely your current Wi-Fi router).  `iptables` is not easy to use.

A tool that's easier to learn and use than raw `iptables` would be `firehol`.  You will have to spend some time learning it but it is much easier than `iptables`.  https://firehol.org/#firehol